# How do go about Regex.Matches group in visual C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following statement, and I want to extract the values of Video[0] and title[0].

```
String text = "< php $video[0]='aEOqMqVWB5s';$title[0]='www.yahoo.com'; ?>";
```

How do I go about using Regex.Matches, and the Groups[0].Value? So in this example, the first group will be `aEOqMqVWB5s`, and the second group will be `www.yahoo.com`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis will create the 2 groups you need. Also, you will have to escape the following characters: $,[,],? and you can do this with "\". So, you're regex will look something like: "< php \$video\[0\]='(.*)';\$title\[0\]='(.*)'; \?>"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
\$(?:video|title)\[0\]='(.*?)'
```

#### Sample Code:

C# example: (*Untested*, to give you an idea for how to start)

```
MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(inputStr,"\$(?:video|title)\[0\]='(.*?)'");

foreach(Match m in mcol)
{
   Debug.Print(m.ToString());  // See Output Window
   // Here you can use   m.Groups[0].Value   or   m.Groups[1].Value
   // adjust your loop accordingly
}
```

#### Regex breakup:

```
\$              = looks for `$` character, need to escape since it has a specific meaning for regex enine.
(?:video|title) = match for either word `video` or `title`, Don't capture group.
\[0\]=          = looks for literal `[` followed by `0` ollowed by `]` and `=`.
'(.*?)'         = lazy match for anything enclosed by single quote `()` makes a group here.
```

#### Recommended read:

An example for [Regex.Matches.Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)

#### Live demo:

[Online Regex tester Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/VBFd0MNl5D)

Comment: If you go down this route, I'd make the first group non-non-capturing so you can tell which group is which.

Comment: @Rawling, Can you please elaborate more ? didn't get your point.

Comment: Well, if you don't capture the `video|title` part of the input, you'll have to reparse the match to find out whether the value in `Groups[1]` is the video field or the title field. If you capture it (i.e. take out the `?:`) you can check `Groups[1]` to see which field it is, and `Groups[2]` to get the value.

Comment: @Rawling, as I understood, `the **first group** will be **aEOqMqVWB5s**, and the **second group** will be **www.yahoo.com**`and it depends if the order of `title` and `video` varies or not. If it varies then non-capturing should be changed to capturing. OP seems to interested in the **value** not the **key** but it depends.